# AJAX в wordpress плагине в switch

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress

Сразу код, который не работает, в конце вопрос =):

Главный файл плагина wordpress:

```
define('UrlPlugin', plugin_dir_path(__FILE__)); // Путь до плагина

switch ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) { // Навигация по сайту
    case '/vyistavit-redaktirovat-golosa':
        include UrlPlugin.'addEditVote/AddEditVote.php';
        break;
}
```

Файл AddEditVote.php:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_hello', 'say_hello' );
function say_hello() {
    echo "УРАААААААААААА!";
    wp_die();
}

//// при хуке действии wp_enqueue_scripts, вызываем функцияю, которая зарегистрирует JS код обработчика AJAX и выставил её после jQuery
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', function () {
    wp_enqueue_script('ajaxAddEditVote', plugins_url('/ajaxAddEditVote.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'), null);
    // До вывода JS, вызванного wp_enqueue_script, выводим JS объект с какими либо значениями
    wp_localize_script('ajaxAddEditVote', 'localizePlugin', array(
        'ajaxURL' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')
    ));
});
```

JS с AJAX запросом, добавленный в предыдущем файле:

```
var data = {
    action: 'hello',
};
jQuery.post(localizePlugin.ajaxURL, data, function (response) {
    alert('Получено с сервера: ' + response);
});
```

Нужно:

- Что бы на определённой странице сайта срабатывал AJAX и все файлы,
  связанные с ним хранились в отдельной папке плагина.
- В коде выше, все пути прописаны правильно (перепроверил много раз),
  экшн для не авторизованных не требуется.
- Если из

> switch

вытащить

> include UrlPlugin.'addEditVote/AddEditVote.php';

И просто разместить в главном файле плагина, то всё работает, но на всех страницах сайта. Как только загоняешь в switch или if, то перестаёт работать и появляется 400 ошибка AJAX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

admin-ajax.php возвращает 400, когда не определена акция.

Следовательно, ваша add_action не срабатывает. Она внутри switch. Наверняка условие в switch неправильное.

**Update**

Условие в switch срабатывает при первичной загрузке страницы. Запускается js файл, ajax вызов срабатывает. Всё хорошо.

Но при запросе ajax на сервер у вас в `REQUEST_URI` находится `admin-ajax.php` и ничто другое! Switch не срабатывает, акция не добавляется, и `admin-ajax.php` возвращает вам 400. Вот такое кино.

Comment: Проверял, но так же не понял.  var_dump($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) показывает - string(30) "/vyistavit-redaktirovat-golosa" . Если include вызвать в if(true) { инклюд }, то всё работает, но на всем сайте. Если вместо true делать проверку на страницу, то уже не работает

Comment: Если до иклюда в switch вызвать echo чего либо, то это что-либо отображается на сайте. Поэтому не понимаю что не так

Comment: Я понял причину и дополнил ответ

Comment: А, вообще, конечно, нужен отладчик или хотя бы debug.log. С отладчиком такие проблемы решаются очень просто.

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснения) очень помогли и суть понял)